# submit input is sending empty answer to a db login checker

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, login-control

I'm building a simple login page with PHP + MySQL.
Sending username and password using inputs and getting status on URL, but everytime I click `submit`, apparently nothing goes to login data check on db.
My index.php code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Integração transporte</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
        <p>Integração Transporte</p>
        <br>
        <form class="login-form" action="includes/login.inc.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="nome de usuário ou e-mail"/>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="senha"/>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My login.inc.php file:

```
<?php

session_start();


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo error_reporting(-1);

    include 'dbh.inc.php';

    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

    //Errors
    //Check if inputs are empty
    if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid = '$uid' OR user_email = '$uid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultCheck < 1) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
            exit();
        } else {
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
                if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
                    exit();
                } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                    //Login the user here
                    $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
                    $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
                    $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
                    $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];


                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
    exit();
}
```

My dbh.inc.php (db connection) file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: root
 * Date: 17/08/18
 * Time: 18:43
 */
#Dados para a conexão com o banco de dados
$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "Lucas@09";
$dbName = "dbtest";

#Executa a conexão com o MySQL
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```

My db: 
[image: db]

How to solve my problem? I just dont know what I need to do now... I'm dumb.

Comment: `$hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);` what is the returned value? Did you use hash?

Comment: You mean ```hashedPwdCheck == true```  and ```hashedPwdCheck == false```?  
When the first ```if``` doens't get the submit, he just ```exit();``` and return ```header("Location: ../index.php?login=error"); ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code.

```
$hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
```

`$hashedPwdCheck` will return false. We don't hash our password `$row['user_pwd']`.

We need to hash our password, for example:

```
echo password_hash("root", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
//$2y$10$UIy0lTtvLV.5GZ2rrQGxUeJEaizxTm891mhpCqj5BFJQaVbVhnsdy
```

[image]

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to PHP... I'm a bit lost about this, can't get this working heh.

Comment: You need to hash your password before saving to database: `user_pwd` should be `password_hash("your_password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

Comment: And if I create the password directly on database?
Users doesn't register, only administratior (me) creates user/pwd.

Comment: What do you mean? You can generate password directly: `echo password_hash("your_password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`. Copy this value to database.

Comment: Sry, I still don't get the idea (or where I need to put this line of code).

Comment: You should create a plain php file (for example `test.php`) to check your value.

Comment: Can't access the page ```The requested URL /integracao/teste.php was not found on this server.``` 

Code: ```<?php
include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

echo password_hash("root", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178497/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-lucas-marra).